# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "td"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

hii all i am very new to automation
my problem is i am getting an error

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "td"
```

when i am trying to select an option from dropdown list
this is my sourch code

```
public void CompanyFilters_Fn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='company._idCell']")).click();
     Select CompanyOptions = new Select(_driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='company._idCell']")));

     CompanyOptions.deselectAll();
        CompanyOptions.selectByIndex(5150);
        CompanyOptions.selectByIndex(5003);

}
```

this is my html code

```
<td id="company._idCell" class="filterValue filterActive filterChanged firepath-matching-node" onclick="showInputElement('pre.myProjectsForm.company._id', this, null, 'auto'); return false;" title="Select to filter by Company">Company: [No Company]</td>
```

these are the options

```
<div id="divSelect" class="inputElement" style="left: -1000px; top: 212px; width:        auto; height: 20px;">
<select id="inputSelect" size="5" style="width: auto; visibility: visible;" multiple="" disabled="">
    <option value="-1">Any</option>
    <option value="0">[No Company]</option>
    <option value="5150">123</option>
    <option value="5203">AutoCarLoanCompany</option>
    <option value="5205">Company_rahul</option>
    <option value="5202">CreditCardCompany</option>
    <option value="5003">IBM</option>
    <option value="5204">June</option>
    <option value="5300">other companyyyyy</option>
    <option value="5001">qa</option>
    <option value="5101">Rahul</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Plzzz help me to get out of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very descriptive, you've given it a `td` when it expects a `select` (rightly so).

So here:

```
 Select CompanyOptions = new Select(_driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='company._idCell']")));
```

You need to change this to give it the `select`:

```
Select CompanyOptions = new Select(_driver.findElement(By.id("inputSelect")));
```