# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span" while selecting a dropdown value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Here I am trying to select a value from dropdown using selenium script but I got this error in the console like

> "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"..

```
public class HomeUserManagement {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"C:\\Users\\UMASHANKAR\\Documents\\selenuim\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

//for login
    driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/dashboard");

driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("abc@xyz.in");

driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("abc123xyz");
    driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();  


//actual code for selecting a value from dropdown

 driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/user");
    Select drpdwn=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-signup-username-container")));
    drpdwn.selectByVisibleText("User Name");
    drpdwn.selectByIndex(0);
```

there are multiple values in a dropdown  I need to select one value in that..

Comment: anybody help me

Comment: Can you post the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce?

Comment: @orde OP has provided the URL... no need for HTML...

Comment: @MosheSlavin There IS a need for the HTML in the question. The site design may change tomorrow and this question will be useless to future readers. The relevant HTML should *always* be included in the question. Having said that, additionally adding a link to the page is many times helpful in case the OP's definition of "relevant" HTML isn't all that's actually needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "td"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884040/org-openqa-selenium-support-ui-unexpectedtagnameexception-element-should-have-b)

Comment: @JeffC I humbly accept your opinion! You are right! Having the HTML in the question is good for future readers! I'll make sure to apply this for future questions! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"
```

...implies that you have used `Select` class to interact with the desired element where as the element was a `<span>`.

To select a value e.g. **User Name** from the dropdown using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
    driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/dashboard");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("email"))).sendKeys("admin@malbork.in");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("NsSaNj@0205");
    driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., 'Dashboard')]")));
    driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/user");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='load']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single>span.select2-selection__rendered"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2-results']//li[contains(., 'User Name')]"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: UserName]

---

Note:

- Always induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` before attempting `click()` method when the page changes i.e. DOM changes.
- In this particular usecase, when you browse to the desired page there is an overlay for which you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` and then invoke the required `click()`.

Comment: yes its working,but i am not getting how it will works,how your taking xpath and all,can you please explain me

Comment: @divyau Check out the updated answer which now includes an explanation. Let me know if any queries.

Comment: can you repeat your _Xpath_ related question please?

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., 'Dashboard')]")));                    this one i didnt get how you taken,for which element it is

Comment: As per your usecase perhaps you don't need to access the url `https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/dashboard` in the first place. Still, preserving your code trials I did invoke the url `https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/dashboard` and before performing any task on that page you need a _WebDriverWait_. So without any visibility to your usecase I induced a _waiter_ for the header element with text as **Dashboard**

Comment: sir i m trying here ,need to select a value in dropdown i got xpath error means element not found

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@title='Malveena']"))).click();      this xpath got error

Answer (score 3):

As the error shows you are using `<span>` tag not `Select`.

The `Select` element you are looking for is `//*[@id="signup-username"]`.

Also, you should use [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait for your locators:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

You should look at [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for...

Hope this helps you!

Comment: if i use this code..i will get exception like this  "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable"

Comment: this html code they were using for dropdown     <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-signup-username-container" title="Select">Select</span>