# when I enter data into "search" button, using selenium how can I write a logic to check whether data is displaying or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here I am trying to select a value from dropdown using selenium script but I got this error in the console like
"Exception in thread "main" 
    `enter code here` org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should 
     have been "select" but was "span"..

```
 public class HomeUserManagement {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"C:\\Users\\UMASHANKAR\\Documents\\selenuim\\chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();

//this code is for login

driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/dashboard");

driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("admin@malbork.in");

driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("NsSaNj@0205");
driver.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();  


//actual code for selecting a value from dropdown

driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/user");
Select drpdwn=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-signup-username- 
container")));
drpdwn.selectByVisibleText("User Name");
drpdwn.selectByIndex(0);

there are multiple values in a dropdown I need to select one value in 
that..`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find the element again... to ensure the text was inputted.

Try something like this:

```
WebElement data=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control input-sm']"));
data.sendKeys("abc" , Keys.ENTER);
WebElement updatedData=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control input-sm']"));
String result =updatedData.getText();
System.out.println(result);
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: sir i didn't get which element need to find again after sending data

Comment: the same element! if that is the element you changed... if you are looking for a different element to load just find it!

Comment: now i found search element again,as same in the above code but its not working

Comment: i have find xpath for table ,which is displaying data,,now it is displaying data in console thank you

Comment: sir in dropdown element  i m getting error,i have edited my problem please check once and guide me..

Answer (score 0):

In your website it is not a traditional select drop down and developer have used Ul and li tags.We have to identify it using either using xpath or css-selector locator. 
"//span[@id='select2-signup-username-container']" : In this xpath I am clicking on the dropdown by identifying the element with span tag having id as "select2-signup-username-container"
//ul[@id='select2-signup-username-results']//li[text()='User Name'] : After clicking we will see the ul tag displayed with child li having text as "User Name".clicking on it will select username in drop down. Your website is loading slow so I used Thread.sleep you can use Actions class or webdriver wait if required.

```
package com.java.stackoverflow;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import com.driver.utils.DriverFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getdriverfor("chrome");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://ecabportal.azurewebsites.net/login");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("admin@malbork.in");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("NsSaNj@0205");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='SignIn']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='User Management ']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement dropdown_ck = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='select2-signup-username-container']"));
        dropdown_ck.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-signup-username-results']//li[text()='User Name']")).click();

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a good answer just on the wrong question... this is the question you are answering...: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56471007/8179099